# Codename one methods not available on android device

Tags: codenameone

The methods that are missing from the apk file are

BorderLayout.centerEastWest()

Dialog constructor with (String, Layout) as arguments.

There are probably more but these are the ones I encountered. I can work around the problem by using alternate methods and constructor but there seems to be a mismatch between the local library and the android build library.

Please note that when building the project I had to use the android.gradle=false hint for the apk to be readable on my older android 2.3.6 device. Without this hint the apk is not accepted on the device.

In addition the theme resource file is not loaded on the device while it is in the simulator. All these problems might be related ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New features are no longer added to the old Ant build pipeline as maintaining it has become unwieldy since Google no longer supports proper versions of play services or other features we need.

We still have it for compatibility for people who built old applications with it but it's version of the Codename one libraries is frozen in time as newer versions of the libraries will break it. Google killed support forthe 2.x device family ages ago in play services so basic things like in-app purchase or proper location API's can't work on those old devices. The problem is that supporting them would make support for newer features MUCH harder.

I've edited the docs to reflect that this flag is deprecated.